# Rename files with same name and extension (usually .pdf) in the sub directories with incrementing number

Tags: powershell-2.0

My folder structure is like this:

Folder 1

- File 1.pdf
- File 2.pdf
- File 3.pdf

Folder 2

- File 1.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 1-1.pdf"
- File 2.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 2-1.pdf"
- File 5.pdf

SubFolder 2.1

- File 2.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 2-2.pdf"
- File 4.pdf
- File 5.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 5-1.pdf"

Folder 3

- File 1.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 1-2.pdf"
- File 2.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 2-3.pdf"
- File 4.pdf ---> Rename this to "File 4-1.pdf"
- File 6.pdf
- File 7.pdf

This is what i was trying, but its certainly wrong. I am using Powershell Version 2.0.

```
$i = 1 
$folder = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xyz\testfolder\pdf_files\"
foreach ($file in $folder){
    if (($file.BaseName + $file.extension) -match ($file.BaseName + 
    $file.extension)){
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName "$($file.BaseName + 
    $i)$($file.extension)" -Verbose -WhatIf
    $i++ 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question through a very kind person. Anyway..here is the PS script that worked for me..

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Foo\Bar\Files\' -Recurse | Where- 
Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
$FileNameCounts = @{}

ForEach ($File In $Files) {
  $BaseName = $File.BaseName

If ($FileNameCounts.Keys -contains $BaseName) {
    $NewName = '{0}-{1}{2}' -f $BaseName, $FileNameCounts[$BaseName], 
    $File.Extension
    $File | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
    $FileNameCounts[$BaseName]++
  } Else {
    $FileNameCounts[$BaseName] = 1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of doing the same thing.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file | Group-Object Name | foreach-object {
        $script:i = 1
        $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
           Rename-Item -newname { "{0}-{1}{2}" -f $_.basename, $script:i++, $_.extension }
}
```

`Group-Object` gives us all the files with the same name, and for each group of names, the first file is skipped and the rest is being renamed.

It also takes advantage of a feature that was designed specifically for this usecase, that `-NewName` can take a scriptblock as a parameter. The scriptblock will be invoked for each pipeline item and the result will be passed to `Rename-Item` as the newname.

Comment: The `-File` requires PowerShell v3. It's just an alternative to ` | Where {-not $_.PSIsContainer}`